# rearanging data from duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have an excel sheet with a list of mothers and students,
Every record shows just one student, but some of the moms have more than one student - meaning they have multiple records.
How do i move the extra students for every mom to another column on the mom's row ?

example:
[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in Excel or Google Spreadsheet? You can do this with VBA, and probably also with a formula (but it'd be a little complicated).  Also please let us know what you're tried, what has/hasn't worked, etc.

Comment: Excel probably has more options, so probably excel. For now I split the spreadsheet into 4 separate sheets (according to the number of students per mother), because i need to automate a web script that reads specific columns from the browser (I want to use iMacros for that).

Comment: ended up doing it manually, using ifcount() to add another counter for the repeating parents, sorting according to new counter and copying the data over. also writing a script to do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short ruby script that does that (thanks to Yanik Rabe)
(The pluralize method in the beginning is not really necessary, just makes prettier error messages...)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# The CSV file to read from
INPUT_FILE = 'sample.csv'

# The CSV file to write to
# This can be the same as INPUT_FILE
# Existing files will be overwritten
OUTPT_FILE = 'sample.out.csv'

# The total number of cells in each row
CELL_COUNT = 10

# The number of cells for each student
# This defines how many columns contain
# student data and will therefore be
# moved to the matching row.
STDT_CELLS = 4

# ----- End of configuration -----

require 'csv'

lines = CSV.read INPUT_FILE

class String
    def pluralize(n, plural = nil)
        noun = \
            if n == 1
                dup
            elsif plural
                plural
            else
                "#{self}s"
            end
        "#{n} #{noun}"
    end
end

class Array
    def real_length
        last_index = 0
        (0..length).each do |i|
            last_index = i if self[i] and not self[i].to_s.empty?
        end
        last_index + 1
    end
end

lines.each_with_index do |line, i|
    next unless line
    if line.length < CELL_COUNT
        missing = CELL_COUNT - line.length
        noun = 'missing cell'.pluralize missing
        STDERR.puts "Warning: #{noun} on line #{i+1} will be filled with an empty string in the output"
        while line.length < CELL_COUNT
            line << ''
        end
    end

    # Check for other entries with the same parent email
    lines.each_with_index do |dline, di|
        next unless dline
        next if i == di
        next if dline.empty?
        if line.first == dline.first
            ((CELL_COUNT - STDT_CELLS)..(CELL_COUNT - 1)).each do |i|
                line[line.real_length] = dline[i]
            end
            lines[di] = nil
        end
    end
end

CSV.open OUTPT_FILE, 'wb' do |csv|
    lines.each do |line|
        csv << line if line
    end
end

puts "Read #{INPUT_FILE} (#{lines.length} lines), wrote #{OUTPT_FILE} (#{lines.compact.length} lines). Have a nice day!"
```